# Changing the prompt style of a virtualenv instance with zsh

Tags: python, zsh, virtualenv

I would like the change my zsh prompt style for every virtualenv instances that I use or create. My actual prompt is like this:

```
declare PS1="%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%} at %{$fg[yellow]%}%m%{$reset_color%} in %{$fg_bold[green]%}%3~%{$reset_color%}"
```

When I activate a virtualenv it just adds some information before the prompt:

```
(the name of my venv)my_prompt
```

Do you know a way to change the colors or styles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can use its [hooks](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#postcpvirtualenv) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

And you can use virtualenvwrapper plugin in the ~/.zshrc,Don't use virtualenv plugin together with virtualenvwrapper.