# How to set `pipenv shell` prompt to match the Terminal's PS1 prompt?

Tags: bash, macos, pipenv

I'm using `MacOS` and `bash`.

I'm using `pipenv` for virtual environments and I really want to make the look of my virtual shell match the look of my standard shell.

When I'm outside of `pipenv`, I set my `.bash_profile` so I could have the time, a green command prompt that shows the full path of my working directory and, if that directory has a git repo, it shows my current branch at the end.

I've searched for the correct file to edit to get the same look for each new `pipenv` shell, but I'm not having any luck finding the right file to copy my profile preferences to.

I'm wondering how I can set it up with my standard `PS1` terminal appearance (colors and current git branch, etc).

Comment: Did you found solution for your problem? If so: please share your solution with community

Answer (score 0):

## pipenv-FAQ

Look at the [shell does not show the virtualenv’s name in prompt](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#shell-does-not-show-the-virtualenvs-name-in-prompt):

> This is intentional. You can do it yourself with either shell plugins, or clever PS1 configuration. If you really want it back, use

### And for the "shell plugins"

You need to look not for "pipenv+bash" but for `virtualenv`+`bash prompt` solutions, such as:

[How do I change the default virtualenv prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406926/how-do-i-change-the-default-virtualenv-prompt)

It's hard for me to recommend "Which way is the best?"

(I'm using `zsh` myself)

Answer (score 0):

> I've searched for the correct file to edit to get the same look for each new pipenv shell, but I'm not having any luck finding the right file to copy my profile preferences to.

For bash, you can create and modify `~/.bashrc`.

The `pipenv shell` command is a wrapper for **virtualenv**, which checks for a `~/.bashrc` file when it activates a virtual environment for a bash shell. Anything in the `~/.bashrc` file gets used in the spawned shell, including prompts, aliases, and other things you customized in your shell.

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
cat: /Users/gino/.bashrc: No such file or directory

$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
bash-5.0$  . /Users/gino/.venvs/test-oiEjhH94/bin/activate
(test) bash-5.0$ ll
bash: ll: command not found
(test) bash-5.0$ exit

$ vim ~/.bashrc
$ cat ~/.bashrc
PS1='\[\e[1;33m\]\u@\W\$\[\e[0m\] '
alias ll="ls -Flh"

$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
gino@test$  . /Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/test-oiEjhH94/bin/activate
(test) gino@test$ 
(test) gino@test$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -Flh'
```

What you can do is to have a `~/.bash_prompt` file where you set all your prompt configs (`PS1`) and a `~/.bash_aliases` file where you set all your aliases. Then, source them both in the `~/.bash_profile` (for the standard shell) and in the `~/.bashrc` (for the pipenv shell).

**~/.bash_prompt**

```
# Format the prompt
# Shows up as:
#   machine-name@current-working-directory$
PS1='\[\e[1;33m\]\u@\W\$\[\e[0m\] '

# other prompt configs
```

**~/.bash_aliases**

```
alias ll="ls -FlhpG"

# other aliases
```

**~/.bash_profile**

```
# For "main" shell (i.e. Terminal, VS Code terminal)

. ~/.bash_prompt
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

**~/.bashrc**

```
# For `pipenv shell`

. ~/.bash_prompt
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

A better solution would be to tell `pipenv shell` or **virtualenv** to reuse the configs in the `~/.bash_profile`, but I haven't got that successfully to work (Terminal, pipenv, VS Code).

---

- macOS 10.15
- bash 5.0 (installed via Homebrew)
- pipenv 2020.8.13