# fish prints python evnironment name prior to my fish prompt

Tags: fish

When I'm activating python virtual environment, fish always prints venv name in brackets before my fish promt.

```
antonio:~/W/s/src > 
antonio:~/W/s/src > source ../env/bin/activate.fish
(env) antonio:~/W/s/src >
```

I want to avoid this `(env)` thing and handle virtual envs by my custom fish_prompt function.

it's doesn't matter, what code I have in `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish` - fish always prints `(env)` and only after that executes my `fish_prompt.fish` function

Comment: This is not your fish printing `(env)`, this is a feature of Python virtual env itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(env)` is not prepended by fish. It is done by the virtualenv itself.

You may disable the behavior by exporting `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1`. See [this answer about setting virtualenv prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20026992/4038448).