# Format python virtual environment name with shell variable PS1 on bash prompt

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-venv, ps1

I'm trying to customize the bash prompt with the shell variable PS1.
How can I access the python virtual environment name to apply color formatting?

PS1 is set to: `\u@\h in \W \$`

I would expect the output to be `user@host in ~ $`

But I get `(base) user@host in ~ $` (`(base) (venv) user@host in ~ $` when using a virtual environment named `venv`)

If possible it would also be great to only display `(venv)` instead of `(base) (venv)`, or is there any use case where the `(base)`-additon makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `activate` script makes a one-time change of hard-coding the name of the virtual environment into the current value of `PS1`. You can disable this by adding `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` to your environment (any non-empty value will do), and use the value of `$(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV)` to customize your prompt however you like.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect.
Searching for the `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` keyword I also found this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406926/how-do-i-change-the-default-virtualenv-prompt