# How to edit bash_profile for a virtualenv?

Tags: unix

My bash_profile has a few customizations for my prompt, including a few lines that show me which git branch I am on. However, when I have a virtualenv activated, it no longer shows me these customizations -- it looks like the virtualenv overrides them. Is there a local bash_profile or some other way to change the prompt configuration when a virtualenv is activated?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what is happening is that virtualenv changes your PS1 variable. All you have to do is avoid this to happen ( maybe editing the bin/activate script or using [hooks](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts.html) )

This post seems to have a similar question: [Changing the prompt style of a virtualenv instance with zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646014/changing-the-prompt-style-of-a-virtualenv-instance-with-zsh)